# Proper way to send multipart/form-data using `fetch` or `request`

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch

This is the structure of the data I want to send to the server:

```
{
   attachment: [File],
   foo: String,
   bar: String
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to send an array of files along with some other data. For storing all this data, I used `FormData()` constructor provided in the JavaScript official API. I am populating the `formData` like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.files.length; i++) {
    let f = this.state.files[i];
    this.formData.append('attachment', f, f.name);
}
this.formData.append('foo', this.state.foo);
this.formData.append('bar', this.state.bar);
```

Sidenote: using React, `react-dropzone` for file upload.
I am now trying to submit this data to the server. I first tried using the Fetch API like so:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: data,
    headers: {
      ...authHeader(authToken)
    }
}
```

Without too much success. Method is `POST`. `authHeader(authToken)` just generates `Authorization: Bearer ...`. Problem was I think that the headers that get specified get overridden by my authentication header.

So I tried using `request` and `request-promise-native`. I did something like:

```
rp({
    url,
    method,
    headers: {
      ...authHeader(authToken)
    },
    formData: data
});
```

With similar results. What is the proper way to send this kind of data with Authorization Header and an array of Files from `FormData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, I managed to send the data with the following configuration:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: data,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        ...authHeader(authToken)
    }
})
```

That is, passing through the `Accept` header seems to have fixed the issue. Please also note that the `Content-Type` header is not set, allowing browser to set it by itself.

Answer (score 6):

This are the options available in the fetch object

```
fetch(url, {
            method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
            cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
            referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
            body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        })
```

If you need to send some custom header to the server just write it like this:

```
headers: {
           "My-Custom-Header": "Custom-Header-Value",
         }
```

And because you want to send a multipart-form data you need to just add the data to the body of the request like this:

```
body: formData
```

If you have your fields inside a form tag you could set your form data like this:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
```

If you are using http authentication there are different authentication schemes, for reference use this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

If your are using basic authorization then you should use something like this:

```
headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password')
         }
```

Comment: This answer covers in the most part what I already wrote. The missing part was: `'Accept': 'application/json'` and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Regarding your HTTP Auth, I already wrote that I handled it with `authHeader`. But thanks.

Comment: @DragosStrugar I am glad you find out your problem. When using the native fetch there are some few headers that you need to set by yourself. Others http client like axios manage those headers for you but that it's not the case of native fectch().